# unable to download private github package through aws codedeploy

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, github, aws-code-deploy

We have a code pipeline hosted on AWS. In the CodeDeploy stage, it installs the packages in our nodejs project. Now one of these packages is a private package hosted on Github on a Pro user account. I have setup the integration with Github. The source was Github version 1, but sinceit wasn't recomended, I changed it to Github version 2, with a proper connection. Now there's an AWS app installed on our repo to manage access. I configured it to allow access to both the nodejs repo and the private package repo. But We're still getting 404 not found when the pipeline runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically I did two things to solve my problem:

1- Move the library from dev dependencies to dependencies in package.json, since our pipeline only installs production packages.

2- Copy over the .npmrc file from home folder to the repo. This way the pipeline knows it has to download from the github registry and not from the npm registry.

Hope this saves somebody's time in the future.